# I'm trying to download a directory from the server via ssh and an error comes up, how do I solve it?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have a server from where I need to download the directory, I try to do it with the paramiko library, but I get an error with the path, tell me how to solve it?

```
import paramiko

hostname = "ip address"
port = 22
username = "root"
password = "root"

transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

filepath = '/root/.aptos'
localpath = r'C:\Users\Tokyo\PycharmProjects\servers\mydirectory'

sftp.get(filepath, localpath)

sftp.close()
```

And I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tokyo\PycharmProjects\servers\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
  File "C:\Users\Tokyo\PycharmProjects\servers\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 810, in get
    with open(localpath, "wb") as fl:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Tokyo\\PycharmProjects\\servers\\mydirectory'
```

Comment: Yes, the directory exists, I created a file inside

Comment: add yoiur ip in /etc/hosts and it will work

Comment: Is there no other way?
It's just that I have several of these servers, and I would like to use a loop to download to all at once

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method is only for files, so your paths should be the to the files, not the directories

So try

```py
filepath = '/root/.aptos/myremotefile'
localpath = r'C:\Users\Tokyo\PycharmProjects\servers\mydirectory\myfile'
```

instead

Comment: Would it be possible to download the directory?

Comment: Yes, but I would recommend using [pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/), which is a paramiko wrapper. Using pysftp you would have to use the get_d method, or get_r if you want it be recursive, some examples [here](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-get-r)